# Create virtual hardware that listens & returns commands back to C# Application

Tags: c#, python-3.x, com, serial-port, pyserial

I'm looking into developing software that would be able to listen for commands sent across the COM1 serial port, interpret them and send back unique data based off of that command.

ex) if the listener reads a command sent as `0x05`, it would send back `0x10`.

We currently have software in C# that sends commands across COM1 to our hardware products, but during development we are not guaranteed to always have hardware available to test on and ensure the GUI controls are functioning properly. This listener would help alleviate that issue. My coworker has been refining a python script that utilizes the `Pyserial` package which I plan on using to handle command protocol.

So ultimately, I am expecting my C# application to have COM1 open and sending commands while the listener program reads any data sent, interprets it and sends back the correct response.  Is this the correct way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) creates virtual com ports on the computer so you can run both programs on the same computer without multiple com ports and loopback cables. This could be handy when doing this kind of things.
Is this the correct way? It sounds to me like it would be easier to add a emulate mode to the C# software when it returns it's own answers without making a complex thing with serial ports and another piece of software that needs maintaining.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this upon my initial investigation, but after you pointed it out again, this seems to be another solution.  Yes doing the emulation within the program itself would help, but we have multiple pieces of software and I wanted to find a more universal answer to this issue rather than implement for each one.